# The exception while decrypting the encrypted file packaged by pyinstaller

Tags: python, encryption, pyinstaller, reverse-engineering, zlib

Recently I want to study how to decompile encrypted files packaged by pyinstaller.
So I wrote the following code:

```
import zlib
import tinyaes
import sys
CHIPHER_BLOCK_SIZE = 16
key = b"lkasbjhfljkabvdf"
pyc_header = b"\x42\x0D\x0D\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x70\x79\x69\x30\x10\x01\x00\x00"
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as en_f:
    with open(f"{sys.argv[1]}_dec.py", "wb") as de_f:
        origin_encrypted_data = en_f.read()
        cipher = tinyaes.AES(key, origin_encrypted_data[:CHIPHER_BLOCK_SIZE])
        decrypted_data = cipher.CTR_xcrypt_buffer(origin_encrypted_data[CHIPHER_BLOCK_SIZE:])
        plaintext = zlib.decompress(decrypted_data)
        de_f.write(pyc_header)
        de_f.write(plaintext)
```

There is no problem with this key, and the encryption algorithm comes from the official source code of pyinstaller (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod01_archive.py)
But whenever I run this code, I get an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    plaintext = zlib.decompress(decrypted_data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

I have tried replacing `plaintext = zlib.decompress(decrypted_data)` with `plaintext = zlib.decompress(decrypted_data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)` but nothing helps

Comment: Can you provide the first 40 or so bytes of the decrypted data in hex or base64 in the question?

Comment: What exactly is *the encrypted file*? The executable created with PyInstaller or one of the encrypted .pyc.encrypted-files extracted with PyInstaller Extractor?